# How to custom Image Size of WordPress product

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using Oritina theme for woocommerce. I want to change the size of **Product Image** to make it equivalent.

[image: Error photo]

You can see that all of products is not equivalent. Some product is smaller/bigger than the rest.

When I set the image heigh to 410px, It's show equivalent size like the photo below:

[image: when edited css - set height to 410px]

It's looked so neatly and straight but when I view on Mobile or make screen miniature .. It's not take responsive Image. It's still keep 410px for the height, and it's very awful.

[image: not responsive image.]

How can I fix it.

Comment: Create a new crop size in the functions.php file?

Comment: check https://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-images/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Woocommerce > Settings > Products > Exhibition and set the proper image size that you desire.